# How to use scrcpy to run mutiple emulated phyicall devices wirelessly?

Tags: remote-debugging, android-wireless

How Do I Use Scrcpy to Run mutiple emulated phyisical devices wirelessy On adb I know it can be done I got it work with cables, just trying to figure out how to run it wirelessly it gets stuck whenever I try to connect the second device sayin it got an error.

I was expecting to be able to emulate both devices instead of just one i forgot to unplug and test.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation here: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/connection.md